# Realization of a p-adic field as a completion of a number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-fields

Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field of characteristic 0. Is it always possible to find a number field $K$ such that $K$ has only one place lying above $p$ and such that its completion at this place is $F$?

If so, is there any reference for this?

Comment: This follows easily from Krasner's lemma.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Algebraization" of $p$-adic fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311189/algebraization-of-p-adic-fields)